# Varnish giving 403 forbidden error in HTML header when customer is logged in

Tags: magento, nginx, varnish, hhvm, varnish-vcl

I'm trying out Varnish for our Magento eCommerce store and I'm using the Magento Turpentine extension which manages Varnish for Magento,

I have it almost working properly for every page but on the product pages when a logged in user visits a page that has not been cached by Varnish before the resulting html page given back to them has a **403 Forbidden nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)** error in the header section of the page, where the logo, navbar etc should be.

[image: capture].

The issue temporarily goes away when I flush the cache and remove the client cookies but it occurs again.

**1.** Any thoughts What could be causing this issue?

**2.** What can I add to my VLC file to fix this? Or even to stop varnish
    from caching all product pages when a customer is logged in? And as
    a last resort to never cache them at all?

My full web stack is Ubuntu 14.4, HHVM, NGINX, Varnish & Magento.

**UPDATE**

I've noticed that if I remove the `store` cookie from the browser the issue does not occur anymore but then I have the issue that a logged in customer cannot be in the correct store for them.

---

In my **NGINX error log**:

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/nginx/error.log
2015/09/25 10:21:47 [error] 6883#0: *9127 access forbidden by rule, client: 127.0.0.1, server: staging.example.ie, request: "GET /turpentine/esi/getBlock/method/esi/access/private/ttl/7200/hmac/792b5a0b692e443b333d05c67da46b43b2894112a529bc9d491ee1ae6587d643/data/.9SNe-3SWNx-0DG1igFbueN2iD6oX0Px5UAy8UKa6aJeS6iGeL-QzDW518ZNfFbSx.UCkgmgsQudLS-7Yw7xlvFq8dRYYHyzvSnedsQr-SIdjJOc6qPPCZDz.thRPlO55ZbfrbyajL10WOM9hY.sW0aISLHNaMh-zKoxa3coOgK.RaVwdxwDQNko-kLgBFCpCi5dlKjeqtwCnbCtxaVlUS5TxWUlMj0x8SwmG3TAsj-dZ6wPu-IqERrZCfx12HzY2EXV4tP04qlcGsvrgKYt91dE-10NL15A2zICMeISM9JCzX-W8n9nyEVGxdedFpDUKBvqM7O3-cTzHs-3ZKCagKOSudNe3eiBaHBFX2yf.vWAlc-E0fr6-NsPuwoHxwCQcdTjC22n4z0Cab8Y5IQI09bAYZXVH0bUOsOVG7n7utY=/ HTTP/1.1", host: "staging.example.ie", referrer: "http://staging.example.ie/kiddies-scarf"
```

---

These are the **page headers**

```
Remote Address:52.7.40.70:80
Request URL:http://staging.example.ie/lace-tumbler
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Age:14
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 28 Sep 2015 10:00:49 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,sv;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:store=ie; currency=EUR; cookielaw=1; frontend=1185f1d3446c7e158bdb4e73572fcbf0; customer_group=1; frontend=1185f1d3446c7e158bdb4e73572fcbf0; external_no_cache=1
Host:staging.example.ie
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://staging.example.ie/crystal
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.99 Safari/537.36
```

In case you're wondering were some of the Varnish headers are, the Turpentine extension removes them.

---

**VCL File**

```
C{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
static pthread_mutex_t lrand_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void generate_uuid(char* buf) {
pthread_mutex_lock(&lrand_mutex);
long a = lrand48();
long b = lrand48();
long c = lrand48();
long d = lrand48();
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lrand_mutex);
sprintf(buf, "frontend=%08lx%04lx%04lx%04lx%04lx%08lx",
a,
b & 0xffff,
(b & ((long)0x0fff0000) >> 16) | 0x4000,
(c & 0x0fff) | 0x8000,
(c & (long)0xffff0000) >> 16,
d
);
return;
}
}C
import std;
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
.first_byte_timeout = 300s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 300s;
}
backend admin {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
.first_byte_timeout = 21600s;
.between_bytes_timeout = 21600s;
}
acl crawler_acl {
"127.0.0.1";
}
acl debug_acl {
}
sub generate_session {
if (req.url ~ ".*[&?]SID=([^&]+).*") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session = regsub(
req.url, ".*[&?]SID=([^&]+).*", "frontend=\1");
} else {
C{
char uuid_buf [50];
generate_uuid(uuid_buf);
VRT_SetHdr(sp, HDR_REQ,
"\030X-Varnish-Faked-Session:",
uuid_buf,
vrt_magic_string_end
);
}C
}
if (req.http.Cookie) {
std.collect(req.http.Cookie);
set req.http.Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session +
"; " + req.http.Cookie;
} else {
set req.http.Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session;
}
}
sub generate_session_expires {
C{
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm now_tm = *gmtime(&now);
now_tm.tm_sec += 7200;
mktime(&now_tm);
char date_buf [50];
strftime(date_buf, sizeof(date_buf)-1, "%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z", &now_tm);
VRT_SetHdr(sp, HDR_RESP,
"\031X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires:",
date_buf,
vrt_magic_string_end
);
}C
}
sub vcl_recv {
if (req.restarts == 0) {
if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
} else {
set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
}
}
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
} else if (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
} else {
unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
}
}
if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "iP(?:hone|ad|od)|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera (?:Mini|Mobi)") {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "mobile";
} else if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "MSIE") {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "msie";
} else if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Firefox") {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "firefox";
} else if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Chrome") {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "chrome";
} else if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Safari") {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "safari";
} else if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Opera") {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "opera";
} else {
set req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent = "other";
}
if (!true || req.http.Authorization ||
req.request !~ "^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS)$" ||
req.http.Cookie ~ "varnish_bypass=1") {
if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?admin") {
set req.backend = admin;
}
return (pipe);
}
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "([^:])//+", "\1/");
if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?") {
set req.http.X-Turpentine-Secret-Handshake = "1";
if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?admin") {
set req.backend = admin;
return (pipe);
}
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "\bcurrency=") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Currency = regsub(
req.http.Cookie, ".*\bcurrency=([^;]*).*", "\1");
}
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "\bstore=") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Store = regsub(
req.http.Cookie, ".*\bstore=([^;]*).*", "\1");
}
if (req.url ~ "/turpentine/esi/get(?:Block|FormKey)/") {
set req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method = regsub(
req.url, ".*/method/(\w+)/.*", "\1");
set req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access = regsub(
req.url, ".*/access/(\w+)/.*", "\1");
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "esi" && req.esi_level == 0 &&
!(false || client.ip ~ debug_acl)) {
error 403 "External ESI requests are not allowed";
}
}
if (req.http.Cookie !~ "frontend=" && !req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method) {
if (client.ip ~ crawler_acl ||
req.http.User-Agent ~ "^(?:ApacheBench/.*|.*Googlebot.*|JoeDog/.*Siege.*|magespeedtest\.com|Nexcessnet_Turpentine/.*)$") {
set req.http.Cookie = "frontend=crawler-session";
} else {
call generate_session;# call generate_session;
return (pipe);
}
}
if (true &&
req.url ~ ".*\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|swf)(?=\?|&|$)") {
unset req.http.Cookie;
unset req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session;
return (lookup);
}
if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?(?:admin|api|cron\.php|checkout|checkout/cart|customer|advancednewsletter|onestepcheckout|onepage|exporter|contacts|iphone|join|sitemap.xml)" ||
req.url ~ "\?.*__from_store=") {
return (pipe);
}
if (true &&
req.url ~ "(?:[?&](?:__SID|XDEBUG_PROFILE)(?=[&=]|$))") {
return (pass);
}
if (true && req.url ~ "[?&](utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|utm_term|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)?|&)(?:utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|utm_term|gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=[^&]+", "\1");
set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(?:(\?)&|\?$)", "\1");
}
return (lookup);
}
}
sub vcl_pipe {
unset bereq.http.X-Turpentine-Secret-Handshake;
set bereq.http.Connection = "close";
}
sub vcl_hash {
hash_data(req.url);
if (req.http.Host) {
hash_data(req.http.Host);
} else {
hash_data(server.ip);
}
hash_data(req.http.Ssl-Offloaded);
if (req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent) {
hash_data(req.http.X-Normalized-User-Agent);
}
if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Store || req.http.X-Varnish-Currency) {
hash_data("s=" + req.http.X-Varnish-Store + "&c=" + req.http.X-Varnish-Currency);
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private" &&
req.http.Cookie ~ "frontend=") {
hash_data(regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^.*?frontend=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1"));
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "customer_group" &&
req.http.Cookie ~ "customer_group=") {
hash_data(regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^.*?customer_group=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1"));
}
return (hash);
}
sub vcl_hit {
}
sub vcl_fetch {
set req.grace = 15s;
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Host = req.http.host;
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-URL = req.url;
if (req.url ~ "^(/media/|/skin/|/js/|/)(?:(?:index|litespeed)\.php/)?") {
unset beresp.http.Vary;
set beresp.do_gzip = true;
if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
return (hit_for_pass);
} else {
if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Set-Cookie = beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
}
unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;
unset beresp.http.Expires;
unset beresp.http.Pragma;
unset beresp.http.Cache;
unset beresp.http.Age;
if (beresp.http.X-Turpentine-Esi == "1") {
set beresp.do_esi = true;
}
if (beresp.http.X-Turpentine-Cache == "0") {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
return (hit_for_pass);
} else {
if (true &&
bereq.url ~ ".*\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|swf)(?=\?|&|$)") {
set beresp.ttl = 604800s;
set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=604800";
} elseif (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method) {
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private" &&
req.http.Cookie ~ "frontend=") {
set beresp.http.X-Varnish-Session = regsub(req.http.Cookie,
"^.*?frontend=([^;]*);*.*$", "\1");
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "ajax" &&
req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "public") {
set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=" + regsub(
req.url, ".*/ttl/(\d+)/.*", "\1");
}
set beresp.ttl = std.duration(
regsub(
req.url, ".*/ttl/(\d+)/.*", "\1s"),
300s);
if (beresp.ttl == 0s) {
set beresp.ttl = 15s;
return (hit_for_pass);
}
} else {
set beresp.ttl = 7200s;
}
}
}
return (deliver);
}
}
sub vcl_deliver {
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session) {
call generate_session_expires;
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = req.http.X-Varnish-Faked-Session +
"; expires=" + resp.http.X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires + "; path=/";
if (req.http.Host) {
if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "^(?:ApacheBench/.*|.*Googlebot.*|JoeDog/.*Siege.*|magespeedtest\.com|Nexcessnet_Turpentine/.*)$") {
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie +
"; domain=" + regsub(req.http.Host, ":\d+$", "");
} else {
if(req.http.Host ~ "") {
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie +
"; domain=";
} else {
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie +
"; domain=" + regsub(req.http.Host, ":\d+$", "");
}
}
}
set resp.http.Set-Cookie = resp.http.Set-Cookie + "; httponly";
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Cookie-Expires;
}
if (req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method == "ajax" && req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access == "private") {
set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-cache";
}
if (false || client.ip ~ debug_acl) {
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Hits = obj.hits;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method = req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Method;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access = req.http.X-Varnish-Esi-Access;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Currency = req.http.X-Varnish-Currency;
set resp.http.X-Varnish-Store = req.http.X-Varnish-Store;
} else {
unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
unset resp.http.Via;
unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
unset resp.http.Server;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Cache;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Esi;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Flush-Events;
unset resp.http.X-Turpentine-Block;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Session;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Host;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-URL;
unset resp.http.X-Varnish-Set-Cookie;
}
}
```

---

**NGINX sites-available/default-staging configuration file**

```
server {
    # Listen on port 80 as well as post 443 for SSL connections.
    listen 8080;
    #listen 443 default ssl;

    server_name staging.example.ie;

    # Specify path to your SSL certificates.
    #ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/yourcertificate.crt;
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/yourcertificate.key;

    root /var/www/staging-hoi/;
    #auth_basic "Restricted website - authorised access only";
    #auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    location / {
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    }


    # Deny access to specific directories no one
    # in particular needs access to anyways.
    location /app/ { deny all; }
    location /includes/ { deny all; }
    location /lib/ { deny all; }
    location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location /pkginfo/ { deny all; }
    location /report/config.xml { deny all; }
    location /var/ { deny all; }

    # Allow only those who have a login name and password
    # to view the export folder. Refer to /etc/nginx/htpassword.
    #location /var/export/ {
    #    auth_basic "Restricted";
    #    auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
    #    autoindex on;
    #}

    # Deny all attempts to access hidden files
    # such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, etc...
    location ~ /\. {
         deny all;
         access_log off;
         log_not_found off;
   }

    # This redirect is added so to use Magentos
    # common front handler when handling incoming URLs.
    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    # Forward paths such as /js/index.php/x.js
    # to their relevant handler.
    location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    ##
    # Rewrite for versioned CSS+JS via filemtime
    ##
    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js)$ {
        rewrite ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(css|js)$ $1.$3 last;
        expires 31536000s;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }
    ##
    # Aggressive caching for static files
    # If you alter static files often, please use 
    # add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    ##
    location ~* \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|t?gz|tif|tiff|ttf|wav|webm|wma|woff|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ {
        expires 31536000s;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }

       # Handle the exectution of .php files.
    location ~ .php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite / /index.php last;
        }
        expires off;

        # --PHP5-FPM CONFIG START (keep fastcgi_param HTTPS OFF)--
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        ##fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
        #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        # --PHP5-FPM CONFIG START--

        # --HHVM CONFIG START--
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; 
        # --HHVM CONFIG END--

        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

My `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is pretty much at it's default settings, I can share this if you need.

Comment: It looks like it is Nginx (or another upstreem host),  not Varnish that is generating the error. Could you show what your Nginx config is?

Comment: @SteveE. Thanks, I added my nginx config to the question.  It seems to have something to do with the `store `cookie which is being set depending on the clients IP and which in turn gives them a particular Magento store view, when I remove the `store` cookes the from the browser the issue goes away but then the user is in the worng store view

Comment: Thanks for that, the Nginx config looks reasonable. Have you tried using the site without Varnish - connecting directly to Nginx, does the issue go away then?

Answer (score 0):

I can see your store is using set of cookies related to Magento multi-store functionality like "store", "currency" or "customer_group". Either way, from what I can see VCL generated with Turpentine handles only "frontend" cookie which is default session cookie in Magento. By handles I mean that it is adding some set of exceptions and is using it in hash.

Take a look at [this feature request](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/97) as well as this [one](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/816) and [this one](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/872)

If I understand it correctly you should be able to add these cookies somewhere in Turpentine configuration if you are running latest Turpentine. Otherwise you will have to modify the VCL probably just copying parts handling "frontend" cookie. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16307426/1661204) which may serve you as inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You should remove

```
  location ~ /\. {
         deny all;
         access_log off;
         log_not_found off;
   }
```

rule from nginx config to avoid this.